# Exit C# Console application when an exception is thrown

Tags: c#

My code reads text from a file.
I need to add a method where if the file is not in the correct location, the program will exit.

```
try {
    TextReader tr = new StreamReader("C:\\textfile.txt");

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            ListLines[i] = tr.ReadLine();
        }
    }
catch (Exception e)
    {
    Console.WriteLine("File not found - the app will now exit");
    }
```

Is it possible, and what commands should I use?

Answer (score 8):

Three options spring to mind.

Firstly, you can just structure your code to return from the `Main` method at that point. Unless you've got other (non-background) threads running, the application will then terminate.

Alternatively, you can just rethrow the exception, e.g. with `throw`; - that will dump a stack trace to the console afterwards, which may or may not be what you want.

Finally, you can use [`Environment.Exit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit) which will terminate the process. For example:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before");
        Environment.Exit(1);
        Console.WriteLine("After");
    }
}
```

Here, `Before` will be printed, but `After` won't be.

Comment: Thanks! I've gone with the Environment.Exit :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Environment.Exit(0); and Application.Exit

```
try {
    TextReader tr = new StreamReader("C:\\textfile.txt");

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            ListLines[i] = tr.ReadLine();
        }
    }
catch (Exception e)
    {
    Environment.Exit(0)
    }
```